# How to run kubernetes service in web browser?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops

I have create a docker image of nodejs app and create a deployment on kubernetes and expose the deployment to the kubernetes service.

when i run **kubectl get svc** it shows **External ip** >>localhost and **Ports**>>3000:30316/TCP but when i put localhost:3000 in broswer it didn't work.

Comment: you should use localhost:30316.

Comment: i already try this but it also didnot work.

Comment: did you try externalip:port

Comment: Yes i did it.. also use curl but it return empty responce.

Answer (score 2):

If your service is `NortPort` type then you can access your app from outside of the cluster by using `http://<Node IP>:<port>`.
Here, if you use minikube(node ip -> `192.168.99.100`) and port is `30316` then you can try by using this: `http://192.168.99.100:30316`.

You can also access your app by using the port-forward mechanism.

following procedure:

- `kubectl port-forward -n <namespace> <deployment pod name> :<deployment C
  ontainerPort>`
- `http://localhost:<forwarded port>`

Comment: Service is LoadBalancer not NotPort.

Comment: You can get your `ip` address and port to access your app by flowing this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#finding-your-ip-address)